# Cant set my customize style with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, class

I'm trying to apply my own class to a div with bootstrap but it isnt working.

This is my header

```
<section class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <h1 class="titulo-blog">CheeseBlog</h1>
                <small>Un poquito sobre mí, es decir, nada interesante</small>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 pull-right hidden-xs hidden-sm redes">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/twitter4.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/googleplus4.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/youtube4.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/facebook4.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/instagram4.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/skype4.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

and this is the class "redes" that i want to apply to my div

```
    .redes{
    margin-top:35px;}
```

and these are my imports

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=">
<title>CheeseBlog</title>
<!--Ficheros JS-->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/miJavascript.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<!--Ficheros CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });
</script>
```

I Hope someone can help me!

Thanks!

Comment: for me it's working, so what exactly not working? what you are trying to achieve with it?

Comment: This is my header

http://imageshack.com/a/img540/5654/xWgtvy.jpg

what i want is to align the social icons with "CheeseBlog" so i need 35px of margin but it just doesnt work, when I add a class to my div it just ignore all the styles.

Comment: try with `.redes{
    margin-top:35px !important;}`

Comment: i tried it already, thanks anyway ;)

Comment: see, here http://jsfiddle.net/m6e9mdfh/1/ it's working, so problem may be somewhere else, may be some other elements is keeping all the icons down and not allowing the margin to take effect.

Comment: Can you show the order of your CSS file and the BootStrap CSS files?

Comment: @Shehary: first, thanks for your help. I dont understand what's happening, i deleted all the code but the code that i wrote here and it didnt work. I wrote the class "redes" in the first line of my css the problem must be in some import:
I will edit the first post with my imports so you can see if there's something wrong

Comment: @AllanChua : Thanks for your answer. I call my css AFTER the bootstrap css if is that what you meant.